# Embedding vs. including Javascript for DOM interaction?

Tags: javascript, dom, requirejs, separation-of-concerns

Every beginners guide to Javascript talks about the evils of embedded scripts.

And I get it: definitely good advice for novices who have no concept of modular design. But every rule has an exception, and since I'm fairly new at web development (but not development in general) I want to ask if the following is a good exception:

I'm building a web application using MVC on the server-side (Django, for the record), and Require.js on the client-side to manage application logic scripts. I'm careful to keep these scripts DOM-agnostic.

It makes sense to me to embed the remaining DOM-interacting code directly in the server-side HTML templates that are defining that DOM. Creating separate JS files that are so minimal and tightly coupled with the content of the templates just feels unnecessary. Am I wrong?

Assuming you've got all application logic tucked away nicely in external files, is it really so bad to sneak a few lines of jQuery in with your HTML to hook that logic up to the DOM?

Comment: I'm curious - why is it preferable to have the server generate a list of required files, then send the list to the client which then runs a script to load the files by inserting script elements, rather than have the server use the list (that it generated) to create markup that the client then uses to load the scripts? The result is identical - a set of script elements created from a list. My preference would be to have the sever do it in the markup since it's likely much more efficient.

Comment: Mostly for caching purposes. As time goes on, I can see the site including a lot more AJAX-provided content. When handling these requests, I don't want the server to send redundant script markup, nor do I want it to concern itself with knowing which scripts the client has already has loaded. For a first-time visitor, this might be a drawback, but the subsequent caching speed (plus ease of development) makes up for it in my book.

Comment: Caching will be exactly the same for the two approaches. Putting script elements in the HTML is more efficient and works in every browser ever released. Inserting them by script introduces risks that simply don't need to be taken and provides zero benefit.

Comment: Well, if there's a lot of AJAX responses, and the server can't assume much about which scripts the client has already executed, won't that result in a lot of already-executed script elements  being run redundantly on the client (e.g. function definitions)? I prefer an environment where the language handles the intricacies of include statements (namely, caching dependencies), and RequireJS gives me that. Since it works as far back as IE6, I wasn't terribly concerned with compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got JS that applies to only one page and there's not very much of it then yes, I would put it directly in the page rather than as a separate JS include.

If you have a *lot* of JS that applies to only one page then a separate JS include gives you the advantage that (after the first request) it will sit in the browser cache rather than being downloaded every time a user refreshes that page. So in that case I'd probably stick with the external JS file.

Having made the decision to include JS in a particular html page, I prefer to include it all as a single block either in the head or at the end of the body - I don't want to have to scan through the html looking for multiple small script blocks buried in the markup. Also if I later decide to move the script to an external file it is easy to do so.

Comment: I should say that many of these embedded blocks will live in "inner templates" that page-level templates will include server-side. So within a particular template file, yes, the embedded JS will be in a single block, but the fully rendered page will include multiple script blocks. I don't really see this being a concern for development purposes, but I wanted to be explicit in explaining my situation.

Comment: Well I said "I prefer...a single block", not "I would insist on a single block" - really you've got to apply some common sense to this and do what works for your situation. In my opinion some people take the whole "separation of concerns" thing _way_ too far, to the point where their objective is to implement a particular "ideal" design pattern rather than to implement something that actually does what the user needs.

Answer (score 0):

See this on where it is going particularly comment around Angular js from google referred to 
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/08/01/rich-javascript-applications-the-seven-frameworks-throne-of-js-2012/

See this Comparison http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more thorough test and comparison

It appears DOM Templates maybe the future. And for my mind better to deal with in terms of debugging.